# Rendring error, whenever i select another activity other than "Empty Activity"

Tags: android

Whenever i create a New Project & select any activity ( other than Empty Activity - which works fine ), i'm getting this "Rendring Problem" and the Activity which i selected not showing in preview Screen ( as you can see ).

What should i do to solve this? Please help me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ekvJ.jpg)

Comment: Error seems to be in xml resource, rebuild project then try, also post your xml and related code. Maybe you deleted floating action button from designer and oncreate() method of activity is holding that default instanstiation code, which raises error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I didn't did aything. I made a new Project and got this. So i tried again by making another new project with different Activity other than "Empty Activity". I tried rubuild, refresh but still it's showing the same. wait i'm adding XML code too.

Comment: No marcos. It's working fine with Real device but this preview screen showing Rendring problem.. Else working smoothly